# When to use const in a function for C

Tags: c

I've been studying for my midterm tomorrow, and I came across this question where I couldn't decide between answers 2 and 3. `PlayingCard` is a `struct`, and `HANDSIZE` is a constant with a value of 5.

The right answer was apparently option 2, but both a friend and I thought that the better choice here would be 3, as we were told that we should use const as good programming practice when we know that the variable isn't going to be changed. Seeing as it isn't changed here, why would option 2 be better than option 3?

```
/* QUESTION: What should go for the definition of isFlush that detects flushes
   1: Nothing
   2: bool isFlush(PlayingCard hand[HANDSIZE]) {
   3: bool isFlush(const PlayingCard hand[HANDSIZE]) {
   4: bool isFlush(PlayingCard ** hand) {
   5: bool isFlush(const PlayingCard ** hand) {
   6: bool isFlush(PlayingCard *** hand) {
   7: bool isFlush(CardFace * hand) {
   8: bool isFlush(CardSuit * hand) {
   9: bool isFlush(CardSuit suits[HANDSIZE]) {
*/
// missing function defintion
    CardSuit suit = hand[0].suit;
    for (int i = 1;  i < HANDSIZE; i++ ) {
        if (suit != hand[i].suit) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This looks like C++, not C.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: How so?  There's no `cout`, and `CardSuit` could be a `typedef`.

Comment: Not really a dupe (different site), but maybe this: [When and for what purposes should the const keyword be used in C for variables?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/204500/356108) will help.

Comment: I'd agree with you and your friend.

Comment: Specifying the number of array elements in the function declarations which will be discarded during compilation and does not change the function signature is misleading. It's not wrong, but it is also not ... proper. In a beginner course it makes people *think* they pass an array, but they don't.

Comment: I'd suggest asking the tutor what the rationale was for disliking 3

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica IMO it serves as a form of documentation

Comment: @M.M Do you actually do that? (I mean, you personally, in your daily programming.)

Comment: I have to agree with @Peter-ReinstateMonica, this causes confusion about the true nature of the parameter, IMO even [] would go , if it's gonna decay why not declare it as so and move on with it.

Comment: @M.M For documentation, it is usually the standard practice to provide *real* documentation, which could also be in the form of a single-line comment or a `/** documentation */` It has greater value.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I try to make my code as self-documenting as possible, yes. Including using array declarators with the expected size as fuction parameters

Comment: @Edenia I don't see how `/* pointer should point to first element of an array of at least 5 elements */ void f(int *p);`  is any better than `void f(int p[5]);`

Comment: @M.M That makes us both, but this is misleading to beginners, which are the ground of S/O. Just what Peter said.

Comment: I see it as an opportunity for students to learn ,  in C this is a fundamental point of the language and undoubtedly it would have been explained by the course already . I would agree with avoiding obscure or complicated constructs but this is not one

Comment: @M.M I hope they learn more than they get misled by this.

Answer (score 3):

> as we were told that we should use `const` as good programming practice
>     when we know that the variable isn't going to be changed

This is true, but only when you pass a pointer to a variable. If you pass the variable by value there is no advantage that I can see.

In this case I agree that the best answer is 3. It is probably too late to ask the author of the question why the correct answer is 2.

Comment: Of course it's good to specify everything const that you can, if only to express intent. But it does prevent errors on the side as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `const` as a hint that the function will not modify something. You can pass a pointer to non-`const` thing to a function that declares it will take a pointer to `const` thing.

We don't have sufficient information to inform you which function declaration will work. I can eliminate options 1, 4, 5, 6, 8 and 9.

I can eliminate option 1 because it would not compile.

I can eliminate options 4, 5, and 6 because you cannot access a pointer with the `.` operator as is being done in the initialization of `suit`.

I can eliminate option 8, because a `struct` or `union` cannot be compared using `!=`.

I can eliminate option 9, because the name of the argument is wrong.

Options 8 and 9 are also unlikely because of the recursive definition required of the type `CardSuit` that is being suggested in the initialization of `suit`.

You asked:

> Seeing as it isn't changed here, why would option 2 be better than option 3?

You seems to have eliminated option 7. I have insufficient information to do so, since `PlayingCard` might not have a `suit` member, whereas `CardFace` might have such a member. If that were the case, the correct answer would be option 7.

But assuming option 7 should be eliminated, then either options 2 or 3 would work for the function. So, to answer your question above in particular, option 3 is superior because it communicates the intention that the function will not modify the elements of the array.

The only advantage option 2 has over option 3 is that it will exclude attempts to call the function with an array of `const` things. You would only want to do that if the function wished to modify the elements.